# Magento2: After delete pub/static folder and making deploy, no css files found

Tags: css, gruntjs, magento2

I searched the web, but found no answer that would work:

I use Magento 2 custom theme and when I made changes to .less file, I wanted to compile files, so I deleted `pub/static` folder and made deploy: `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy.`
After that, no css files are found in `pub/static/frontend/<Theme>/default/css`. 
Also, when I use `grunt less`, I got errors:

```
>> Destination pub/static/frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/css/styles-m.css not written because no source files were found.
>> Destination pub/static/frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/css/styles-l.css not written because no source files were found.
>> Destination pub/static/frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/css/email.css not written because no source files were found.
>> Destination pub/static/frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/css/email-inline.css not written because no source files were found.
```

I am in a developer mode.

Does anyone have any solution for this?

Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same issue, when I did `grunt refresh` I got the same errors.

To resolve this I removed `var/di`, `var/cache`, `var/generation`, `var/page_cache` and the contents of `pub/static` folder (be careful not to remove `pub/static/.htaccess`).

Then I tried: `grunt exec:themename`

If successful do, `grunt clean`

If successful do, `grunt refresh`

And then, `setup:static-content:deploy`

This worked for me.

Comment: I suggest against running `setup:static-content:deploy`. That is not a necessary step as grunt should take care of all of that.

Answer (score -1):

You need to retrieve the file .htaccess from the pub/static folder.

I found it here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/pub/static/.htaccess

*Check the version you use of magento